# Unable to compile a template

Tags: templates

I can't use [this template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/two-column-one-page-cv) with TexStudio. I tried XeLaTex and LuaLaTeX but didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The template can be compiled as long as you have all the needed fonts installed.
As you can read in the template preamble:

```
% This template uses several fonts not included with Windows/Linux by
% default. If you get compilation errors saying a font is missing, find the line
% on which the font is used and either change it to a font included with your
% operating system or comment the line out to use the default font.
```

Comment: Could you please post the fonts need all? I can't find them exactly. I got a strange errors.

Comment: @SameirDeif which OS are you using `Hoefler and other fonts` might be mac specific fonts. hence karlkoeller mentioned comment lines inside `.tex` "fonts not included with Windows/Linux".  Have a look at [fontspec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) `General font selection`

Comment: Needed fonts are `Hoefler Text`, `Gill Sans`, and `Zapfino`. If you don't have the chance to install them, you can always overcome this by downloading the alternative template, as described at the botton of the web page where you dowloaded this one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try to find another one ... :)